# multiple Dynamic Distribution list with same user

Tags: exchange-2013, distribution-lists

I am sure it is an easy one but I am new to this platform (Exchange2013) and still learning.

Given 3 users:

```
Joe - Head
Bob - Boarding, Kitchen
Lilly - Teacher, Boarding
```

Question 1: How do I tag these onto one person (i.e. Boarding AND Kitchen)

I would like to create the following Distribution lists:

```
Boarding: Bob, Lilly, Head 
Kitchen: Bob, Head 
Teacher: Lilly, Head
```

Question 2, How do I filter those tags so I don't need to type/click everyone through?

It seems very logical that given some fields can be filtered with some rules but when I tried to use whitecards it didn't work.

Could someone direct me to the right path how to deal with this?

I have the 300 staff and I don't want to manually delegate them every time. I thought if I create some tags in the AD then I can filter it down and that can be populated in DDL.

Obviously I am doing something wrong. Thank you for your comments in advance and happy to learn from my mistake.

Comment: Are your DDLs not populating at all or are they just not getting the right users?

Comment: I can't find the method to filter them down to groups.